# Android to iOS is possible ? or zero development?

Tags: garbage

Garbage Garbage Garbage Garbage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**. It is not possible to convert an android app to iOS using a tool. You have to develop app in iOS platform using iOS SDK. There are some cross platform SDK are available like **PhoneGap** there you can develop app for both android and iOS. However for an existing app cant do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert the app if it was written in Java. But here are some recommendations for the future:

For applications that include 3D graphics, I would recommend [Unity](http://unity3d.com/)

If you're looking for simpler applications, take a look at [Cocos2D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocos2d) I don't have any experience with Cocos but it is [said](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/2269) to be portable.

But if you're looking for native GUI widgets, I don't think there is a way to do that.

Note: The answers are for ios-android only. Unity is said to support Windows Phones soon, though.